# Help with identifying rip off ARC HP Chip

Tags: microcontroller, identification, eeprom

I am really tired of 30$ HP Aliexpress magic chips worth 0.5$ in BOM.

Usually I did not care that much about the price as those ARC chips are more less permanent. However this time curiosity took over!

The story:

I have recently bought a printer with two ARC cartridges and two genuine inks. Printer stays that one of two ARC cartridges are not for use in this printer (magenta). All two ARC chis are probably from same batch as looks the same. However cartridges are almost empty, thus used in this printer before. Usually this message means that someone has upgraded the firmware and printer just declines using these rip off chips. This would make sense if both of them stopped working while only one did. That made me curious and trying several different things.

What I found is:

- when buying a pack of four chips, sometimes a black one is a "master" chip used to reset all others: this does not make any sense as one can buy chips separately and have a combination like I do
- there are two kinds of ARC chips: "dumb ones" which printer cannot really understand, that works but shows no ink level; "smart chips" that "copies" what is on genuine HP chip and have ink level that resets either automatically after 50% depletion or by swapping cartridges
- chips have NO recognition what so ever: four CMYK ARC chips looks identical so data should be identical as well; however I have found that swapping chips from cyan to magenta cartridge and putting it in correct position (so cyan with magenta chip in cyan) made printer display on the screen that counterfeit cyan is installed?!
- while HP laser printers use 2 pin (Maxim 1wire communication protocol I think) chips, all inkjet based printers uses 4 pin chips
- No Chinese company will ever use anything sophisticated in their design they are to sly for that; for me the easiest way for ARC chip would be to use EERAM that would reset itself to default "100% ink" value after poweroff; Crypto chips and other fancy solutions are out of equation

[image: ARC on my two cartridges]

Yellow: front

Blue: back

Magenta: suspicion

This is a chip that I have. I am not able to make out which pin is which. Taking a look at generic EEPROM or EERAM pinout it does not make a lot of sense. For sure would be easier with logic analyser that I do not have... That came the idea to check on other generic ARC chips for this same type of cartridge.
[image: Aliexpress/Alibaba chip]

As all chips mus have same pinout for same printer I have tried to find another ARC chip that is not covered in epoxy. This is the best one I could find. Right now it makes even less sense than before. Now even pins do not look to be the same on both chips.

I thought that three magenta legs on 1st IC could be VCC, A1, A2, A3, that would make opposite legs GND, WC, SDA, SCL. But checking EERAM data-sheet from Microchip would suggest that it is very different than that.

Have anybody has any experience with chips like that?

Comment: What makes you think that a small Chinese company wouldn't be able to build some more or less complex logic with i.e. Verilog and have it manufactured as an ASIC? The fact that one of them is a chip-on-board "blob" makes that very likely - the company saves on packaging their custom ASICs by just directly bonding the silicon die to the PCB. Have you tried decapsulating one of them to look at the actual silicon?

Comment: There are two clues making me think like that. Of course these are just clues and for sure nobody will ever give us a ready to use schematic. First of all is that neither HP use any sophisticated technology in their chips, most of the time it were just EEPROMs. Second of all is that HP has 100+ different chips that are not so different apart of a data on it. It makes no sense for me, even with Chinese prices to make a custom ASIC for each cartridge that still cannot be convincing enough for the printer to think that it is a genuine chip.

Comment: There's really just one way to find out what chip is hiding under that black blob on the PCB: Decapsulate it and look at the silicon. The bare dies of almost all general-purpose chips have markings indicating at least the manufacturer, and often also the part number. It should be possible to remove the black epoxy blob with an aggressive solvent like dichloromethane or 1-chlorobutane. Before you handle those solvents, though, please look at their safety datasheets and take the necessary precautions to protect yourself from any potential dangers.

Comment: @NixonMroq economics of scale say that HP doesn't produce an inkjet cartridge type that they're not selling a million times. Ergo, enough volume for a cheap ASIC. I do agree, it's most likely the same ASIC used across different devices, maybe with just some laser-burnt metal layer for ID programming or something. Who knows – it's all speculation. You'll have to look at the actual IC.

Comment: (your "can't be sophisticated" argument doesn't work at all. That's just wishful thinking, as far as I can tell. If I was selling millions of printers each year and was very worried about third-party replicas of my cartridges, I'd make my cartridges have internal unreadable memory that contains a serial ID, signed by my private factory key, and I'd make the printer check the signature each time, much like a SIM card; I'd also roll out software updates revoking leaked signatures used to build counterfeits. All doable with an ASIC that costs cents in volume.)

Comment: Okay, so far so good. I was able to find i2c address for both genuine chip as well as for ARC. I think that I need to invest into better programmer. Trying to read data from both of chips gave some results but very mixed. At the moment being I was not able to have consistent repetitive read. By that I mean sometimes it works fine and get some data back from the chip and sometimes it cannot even find i2c address for the device. It is almost like bad connection or something. Ill order something cheap build on CH341 and will try again.

Comment: The problem I have is that for sure these are EEPROMs but without any precise markings. Checking datasheet of EERAMs stays that in order for the function to work there must be a capacitor enabling it. However if we will take a look at different "brands" of ARC chips for same device, some of them are absolutely bare bone without any component apart of IC itself. So I am highly probably working with some chinese Microchip knock-off without any data-sheet.